# Add custom form before merge

Tags: gitlab, webhooks, githooks

The repository is hosted on Gitlab. I want developers to provide some input before creating the merge request. I have explore the web hooks but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for something called "Description Templates" that let you define content you want your contributors to provide in either Issues, Merge Requests, or both. Documentation is here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/description_templates.html

You can also set defaults in your project settings if you have issues or merge requests enabled.

[image: project settings for default issue template]

Comment: Thank you Adam for answer!!! Description template is optional, I want to make it mandatory, can I use hooks?